# I want to display the days and date also by the relationship between the coach and working times

Tags: php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4, laravel-8

Here a want to add Appointments available for the coach by using two tables...one for date_days the second for trainer and I make a 1-m relation between two tables.

`Dateday Table...`

```
class Dateday extends Model
{

    public function trainer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Trainer::class, 'trainer_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
 Trainer Table...
```

```
class Trainer extends Model
{
    public function datedays()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dateday::class);
    }
}
```

```
Trainer index ...
```

Show this way you give me an error, And I want To add a day and date and start_date/end_date to the index page for trainer Who can do this??

```
 @foreach ($trainers as $trainer)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $trainer->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $trainer->firstname }}</a></td>    
        <td>{{ $trainer->lastname }}</a></td>    
        <td>{{ $trainer->phone }}</a></td>    
        <-- Show this way you give me ero -->
        <td>{{ $trainer->dateday->day}}</a></td>  
        <td>{{ $trainer->dateday->date}}</a></td>  
      </tr>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Trainer` class, you have defined a function dateday**s**, but in your template you are using `$trainer->dateday` without the **s**.

**Regarding your edit**
`$trainer->datedays` is a Collection of all the datedays associated with the trainer (because of the `->hasMany`), so you cannot get the property of an individual item. If there should only be one date, the relation should be changed (`->hasOne`), or if there should be more dates possible, you should think about how you want to show that. If you (for example) only want to show the first date you could use `{{ $trainer->datedays->first()->day }}` or you could loop over all dates using `@foreach ($trainer->datedays as $dateday)` and use `{{ $dateday->day }}` in the loop.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just modified it, but it didn't work. A new error has appeared.Exception
Property [day] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: E:\bool-project\resources\views\admin\trainers\index.blade.php)

Comment: I've edited my answer to account for this new error.

Comment: Yes, it worked and I like what I want, thank you so much.